# Hangfire creating suspended SQL Server threads

Tags: sql-server, hangfire

Our application is using Hangfire to handle incoming messages towards our backend DB/Application.

Hangfire is using SQL Server 2019 Standard and has 50 workers on one server. We handle ~1500 messages per hour.

We face this issue :

1. When a batch of 1500 messages arrive, we see ~250 threads in our SQL Server.
2. Message handling jobs are completed
3. When the next batch of 1500 messages arrive, we see a number of ~250 NEW threads in our SQL Server. This continues to happen until our SQL Server is going into thread starvation.

I am not the dev of our application. Any hints why Hangfire keeps creating new threads while others just stay in "suspended" state? They are released ~1.5 hour after they are created.

[SQL_Server_Threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjsVq.jpg)

I tried using fewer workers, but the same issue happens again.

Comment: A suspended thread means that thread is waiting on some resource to become available; like a lock, or some I/O completion. What kind of work is being done by these threads, and what else is happening on the server? Also, is this constantly happening? Or does it only happen intermittently?

Comment: It only happens when these batches of messages are coming. At normal operation, we have 200 threads active. It is like Hangfire (or the process/job that Hangfire is calling) does not release the threads even when the job is completed.

Comment: probably a dumb question, but you're sure the transactions are being committed? I don't know much about Hangfire, but I know for a lot of ORMs, if you don't explicitly say "commit" things just kind of hang there.

Comment: If you restart the Hangfire server do all the sleeping threads suddenly disappear? Hangfire is just orchestrating .NET code written by humans, so the .NET code is still vulnerable to all the usual issues such as forgetting to wrap all of your `IDisposable`s like `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` in `using` blocks and so leak connections.